# Android Marshmallow Keystore SecurityException

Tags: android, keystore, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to implement functionality similar to [Android Keystore Direct access](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-keystore).  The code is making use of IPC and an exception is thrown when mRemote.transact was called (IKeystoreService.java line 54)

This works well on versions of Android before Marshmallow (API 23).  I know the permissions model has changed since.

The exception is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at com.example.utilities.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.test(IKeystoreService.java:55)
        at com.example.utilities.security.KeyStoreKk.state(KeyStoreKk.java:93)
        at com.example.utilities.security. Cryto.isPasswordPinEnabled(Cryto.java:198)
        at com.example.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Is there a particular permission I need to check for during runtime? Or is this another problem altogether?

Comment: have you got the solution? right now i am facing the same problem.please let me know if you have solution.